# Embed Image in Html and Load in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, html, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I know how to load the images in WebView, now I am trying to embed an image in html and load in UIWebView.
The following are the code which I am using,

```
NSArray*    paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString*   documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString*   folderPath =  [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"iOSDevices"];
NSArray*    filesCount = [[NSFileManager defaultManager ] folderPath error:nil];
NSString* path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",folderPath,[filesCount objectAtIndex:0]];

    NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><img src=\"%@\" type=\"jpg\" width=\"320\" height=\"480\"></body></html>", path];
    [_webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

image name not available,path only get image path,not give image in path,add image name in tag

Comment: I tried that too. @"<html><body><img src=\"page01\" type=\"jpg\" width=\"320\" height=\"480\"></body></html>". not working

Comment: I tried that too. @"<html><body><img src=\"page01.jpg\" width=\"320\" height=\"480\"></body></html>". where page01.jpg stored

Comment: Working working :). Adding the name and setting the base url made it work

Comment: But it is not fitting the screen:(. Do you know how to give 100% width and 100% height ? I tried it is showing some warning.

Comment: the image size set only the browser size,set web view fill in image

Comment: I have given Scaling mode as scale pages to fit. And mode as scale to fill. Still some white spaces are coming

Comment: check image have empty spaces in sides

Comment: Nope. They don't. But if I give harcoded values, the image is fit. But I don't want to do that because it should support in iPad too.

Comment: Is it not possible to set width and height as 100% ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to load your image from local, just add this `file://`  infront of src, like

```
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><img src=\"file://%@\" type=\"jpg\" width=\"320\" height=\"480\"></body></html>", path];
```

and check if you are displaying image "jpg" or "png", and check you are giving correct `type` in `img` tag

The html string should be,
`<img src="file:///Users/file/...some other paths../Documents/Images/imag.png" type="png" width="320" height="480">`

Comment: Is it not possible to set width and height as 100% ?

Comment: you can, give width=\"100%%\", and height=\"100%%\", we have to give '%%' to escape this character '%'

Comment: hi cyril, if you found my answer is useful, just click tick, below the vote up number.

Comment: Actually first the html problem solved by Nannav first. I am up-voting yours. But I am would like to select tick for both of your replies